# Python.Net: how to execute modules in packages?

Tags: python.net

I'm not a Python programmer so apologies if I don't get some of the terminology right (pacakages, modules)!

I have a folder structure that looks something like this:

```
C:\Test\System\
C:\Test\System\intercepts\
C:\Test\System\intercepts\utils1\
C:\Test\System\intercepts\utils2\
```

The last three folders each contain an empty `__init__.py` folder, while the latter two folders (\utils1, \utils2) contain numerous .py modules. For the purposes of my question I'm trying to execute a function within a module called "general.py" that resides in the \utils1 folder.

The first folder (C:\Test\System) contains a file called "entry.py", which imports the .py modules from all those sub-folders:

```
from intercepts.utils1 import general
from intercepts.utils1 import foobar
from intercepts.utils2 import ...
..etc..
```

And here is the C# code that executes the above module then attempts to call a function called "startup" in a module called "general.py" in the \utils1 folder:

```
const string EntryModule = @"C:\Test\System\entry.py";

using (Py.GIL())
{
    using (var scope = Py.CreateScope())
    {
        var code = File.ReadAllText(EntryModule);
        var scriptCompiled = PythonEngine.Compile(code, EntryModule);
        scope.Execute(scriptCompiled);

        dynamic func = scope.Get("general.startup");
        func();
    }
}
```

However I get a `PythonException` on the `scope.Execute(...)` line, with the following message:

```
No module named 'intercepts'
File "C:\Test\System\entry.py", line 1, in <module>
   from intercepts.utils1 import general
```

I'm able to do the equivalent of this using IronPython (Python 2.7), so I assume I'm doing something wrong with Python.Net (rather than changes to how packages work in Python 3.x).

I'm using the pythonnet 3.0.0 NuGet package by the way.

**Edit**
I've tried importing my "entry.py" module as follows:

```
dynamic os = Py.Import("os"); 
dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");                   
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(EntryModule)); 
Py.Import(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(EntryModule));
```

It now appears to get a little further, however there's a new problem:

In the "entry.py" module you can see that it first imports a module called "general", then a module called "foobar". "foobar.py" contains the line `import general`.
When I run my C#, the stack trace is now as follows:

```
No module named 'general'
File "C:\Test\System\intercepts\utils1\foobar.py", line 1, in <module>
import general
  File "C:\Test\System\entry.py", line 2, in <module>
from intercepts.utils1 import foobar
```

Why can't the second imported module ("foobar") "see" the module that was imported immediately before it ("general")? Am I even barking up the right tree by using `Py.Import()` to solve my original issue?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a change in how Python 3 handles imports, compared to 2, and nothing to do with Python.Net.

In my "foobar.py" module I had to change `import general` to `from . import general`. The issue is explained [here](https://nerdparadise.com/programming/python/import2vs3) but I've included the pertinent section below:

[image]